# Scope of dynamic view objects in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

What happens to a view object in python after the original object have been deleted? For example,

```
a = {'foo': 1 , 'bar': 2, 'baz': 3 }
b = a.keys()   # => dict_keys(['bar', 'foo', 'baz'])
```

At this point, if any changes are made to the dictionary, they are reflected in b. For example,

```
a['qux'] = 4
print(b)  # => dict_keys(['bar', 'qux', 'foo', 'baz'])
```

However, when the dictionary is deleted, the dynamic variable still contains all the value of the keys from the deleted dictionary.

```
del a
a        # NameError: name 'a' is not defined
print(b) # => dict_keys(['bar', 'qux', 'foo', 'baz'])
```

**Question**

In essence, I want to know if I have to **always** make sure I delete any variables with the keys values even after the dictionary is deleted. Can this will be a potential cause for a memory leak if the dictionary is large?
Any feedback will be appreciated.

**Side Note:**

And, yes I know I can put the keys in a list:

```
c = list(a.keys())
```

but I am using view objects because of their smaller memory footprint in comparison to list.

Comment: the name `a` was deleted but `b` still holds a reference to the actual object i.e the dict keys so the object cannot be deleted.

Comment: Well, you can also do `b = a; del a`, and `b` is still there despite `a` has been deleted.

Comment: @KevinGuan, because you are referencing the object that a points to not the name a

Comment: Just a note: It's quite rare to go around explicitly calling `del` in Python -- perhaps the most common valid use is to remove an item from a collection by its index, i.e., `del foo[key]`. `del a` should not be read as "delete the object named `a`", rather, it should be read "delete the name `a`"; That is, `del` simply unbinds names. If there are other names or references to the object once pointed to by `a`, then the object will persist in memory. If not, the memory will be freed. Point is, if you are using `del` a bunch in your code (which you may not be), it's probably not necessary.

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Side-note: `del` is not a function, it's a keyword statement. You don't need (and generally shouldn't use) parentheses with it, any more than you use them with `return`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend not to use the term *variable*. Better use *name that allows access to an object*. For your example `a` and `b` are names for the objects dictionary and the keys of a dictionary. In Python 3 `dict.keys()` gives you a key-view object that reflects the changes in the underlying dictionary. Therefore, the key-view object keeps a reference to the dictionary.

So you don't delete the dictionary but rather the name pointing to it. Only if there are no more names (references to the dictionary) left, will the garbage collector remove the dictionary.

If you program in a structured way with functions that do not work on global objects, memory leaks are rather rare. In practice `del` is typically used sparingly.

Answer (score 0):

`del` only decreases reference counter to an object in python's underhood. Dictionary itself will be deallocated from memory (*disposed*) <s>far later,</s> when no references left active in program.

When you save `keys()` product in a variable, you increase dict's reference counter, additionaly to dict's variable itself. Variable will not be deallocated while any reference left to it.

I can express your code in very simple, but absolutely same construction:

```
a = dict()
b = a # reference only
del(b)
# dict is not garbage-collected, as a still holds the reference

a != None # True
```

Comment: In CPython (the reference interpreter), if the reference count actually drops to zero, the object is disposed of _immediately_, not later, let alone "far later". The rest of your post is correct, but if a reference count ever drops to zero (including all references held implicitly elsewhere), the object is gone, immediately. Only time you get non-deterministic cleanup is when a reference cycle exists; the cyclic garbage collector runs intermittently, so an unreferenced cycle might take a while to clean up.

Comment: Thanks for correction. Although, i was talking about practice and not clean theory. So objects regularly depend on each other; releasing them from memory may take time in real apps, while application passes to another foreground tasks. I opened this to myself while working with python in C. However, it was in earlier 3.x versions and it was headache.